# What is the least number of vertices that 2 edge disjoint spanning trees can have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let graph $G$ have 2 edge-disjoint spanning trees.

This means none of the edges are common in the 2 spanning trees.

What is the least amount of vertices $k$, that $G$ can have?

Give an example of such a graph that has 2 edge-disjoint spanning trees but only $k$ vertices.

---

Would the answer just be this:

[image]

The two spanning trees are $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, and they are edge disjoint.

What about if an artibary amount of vertices $k'$ is given? Then what would the graph look like such that $k' \geq k$ and we still only have 2 edge-disjoint spanning trees?

Two questions^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as for your example 12 and 21 are the same edge I believe so that won't work. [I assume we are talking simple undirected graphs here.]

Actually there is a simple graph on 4 vertices with 2 edge-disjoint spanning trees...in particular $K_4$ (where the vertex-set is $\{1,2,3,4\}$) has
one spanning tree with the edges $12,23,34$ and another where the edges are $31,14,42$.

And 4 is the smallest such integer for simple graphs. A graph on $k$ vertices would have to have at least $2k-2$ edges $(k-1$ edges for each spanning tree on $k$ vertices) to have two edge-disjoint spanning trees, and this is impossible for simple graphs on 3 or fewer vertices [make sure you see why].

Comment: How did you come up with the $2k-2$ number

Comment: See my edit......

Comment: I'm not sure how that guarantees *exactly* 2 disjoint spanning trees. I understand that for each spanning tree you need $k-1$ edges. But I am not sure how multiplying by 2 guarantees exactly 2 disjoint spanning trees?

Comment: Well it does not *guarantee* two edge-disjoint spanning trees but it is *necessary* for there to be two edge-disjoint spanning trees. You notice that for $K_4$ I proved that there are two disjoint spanning trees, by explicitly specifying the edge set in each of the two edge-disjoint spanning trees.

Comment: The above proof that I gave has two parts 1. Establish that graphs on 3 or fewer vertices do not have two edge-disjoint spanning tress because they do not have enough edges. 2. Show that the complete graph has two edge-disjoint spanning trees by **explicitly specifying** the edge set of each of the spanning trees.

Comment: Right, but that is for $k=4$, what if we have $k=n$, how would we specify the edge set then?

Comment: You asked for **the least** number of vertices that a graph can have to have two edge-disjoint spanning trees. I proved that the least number of vertices such a graph can have is 4 and then I  gave an example of such a graph with 4 vertices that has two edge-disjoint spanning trees. That suffices to answer the question.

Comment: As for general graphs $G$ on $n \geq 4$ vertices, not all such graphs will have two edge-disjoint spanning trees. If $G$ has a cut edge then it will *not* have two edge-disjoint spanning trees no matter how large the number $n$ of vertices that $G$ has.